# What does it mean for a matrix to have total support?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading a paper "Concerning non-negative matrices and doubly stochastic matrices" (Sinkhorn) and I do not understand the definition of a matrix with total support. Here is the definition:

"If $A$ is a nonnegative square matrix, $A$ is said to have total
support if $A \neq 0$ and if every positive element of A lies on a positive
diagonal."

Could someone give an example of a 3x3 non-negative matrix with total support and another one without total support? I am not really sure what is meant by positive diagonal, I am only familiar with the main diagonal.

Comment: Per https://www.jstor.org/stable/1994701, a diagonal is a collection of elements one from each row and one from each column, or in other words it will consist of $a_{i,\sigma(i)}$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$ for some permutation $\sigma$. A positive diagonal is one with all positive elements. So this means that for a matrix to have total support, if an element is positive then there is some diagonal containing that element so that all other elements of the diagonal are positive. An example where this doesn't happen would be a matrix with just one positive entry.

Comment: The Sinkhorn article is weirdly hard to find on Google Scholar.  FWIW a PDF is at https://msp.org/pjm/1967/21-2/pjm-v21-n2-p14-s.pdf.

Comment: @Ian: [Please don't answer in comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1560/330413); answers are for answers!